# How to generate number with one more digit than previous one?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this:

```
 generateNumber() {
    Random random = Random();
    int _randomNumber = random.nextInt(900) + 100;
    number = _randomNumber.toString();
  }
```

I want to loop this and after each one generate number with one more digit for example:
233, 9786, 11215, 654123
How? Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a note. You should not create the `Random` instance inside the method which are going to create the random number. Instead, create a global instance of `Random` and reuse that. Especially if you are going to call the method more than once. :)

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode, where N is the number of maximum digits:

```
lower_limit = 0

for i in 1, .., N:
    upper_limit = 10^i
    generateNumer(lower_limit, upper_limit)
    lower_limit = upper_limit
```

Note that your random number generator should exclude to choose the upper_limit since its digit number is too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the floor(log_10(n)) + 1 of any base 10 number, n, it'll give you the number of digits in n.

ref:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384917/relation-between-number-of-digits-of-a-number-and-its-logarithm